# Class or component cannot be found

Tags: modelica

I was trying to create a heat exchanger (liquid-liquid) based on the condensor (AirConditioning.HeatExchangers.Condensor) from the AC library.
And the issue is there is an error telling me "Class or component 'tion' not found in HXCoolant refrigerant".

I checked the ThermoFluidPro.PipesAndVolumes.HXCoolant, but didn't find any component names "tion".

```
 ThermoFluidPro.PipesAndVolumes.HXCoolant refrigerant(
redeclare model HTCoefficient =
       ThermoFluidPro.HeatTransfer.HTPipe.KcSimpleTwoPhase 
  "HTCoefficientRefSide (F_user=CF_RefrigerantSideHeatTransfer)",
redeclare replaceable model FrictionLoss =
    ThermoFluidPro.PressureLoss.PLossHexChannel.DensityProfilePressureLossHX
    (
    p0_in=23.6e5,
    p0_out=23.5e5,
    h0_in=450e3,
    h0_out=270e3,
    mdot0=0.02),
    tion=geometry.tubeOrientation,
init=coolantChannelInit,
redeclare package Medium = ThermoFluidPro.Media.Technical.R134a)
                 annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-30,-78},{10,
        -38}}, rotation=0)))
```

Is there anyone have this type of error before? And how do you fix it?

Thank you

Comment: I have never used that library, but I am pretty sure that you have a typo or copy&paste error and `tion` is supposed to be a full word like Orientation, annotation, direction or something else. Have a look at the parameters of `ThermoFluidPro.PressureLoss.PLossHexChannel.DensityProfilePressureLossHX` to see what input it expects.

Comment: Actually, I thought about whether "tion" is part of the the word such as orientation and direction, but those words were not working. I will go and check the name of the parameters. Thank you so much for your advise.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late answer, but the solution as implicitly suggested by others is to remove the line in your code that reads:

```
tion=geometry.tubeOrientation,
```

It seems as it was just the result of bad copy&paste. I assume it originally was `orientation` or `tubeOrientation`, but as far as I can tell `ThermoFluidPro.PipesAndVolumes.HXCoolant` does not have parameters with such names.